# How to add or multiply two i16 in Rust to form an i32 without overflowing?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow

How to add or multiply two `i16` numbers in Rust into a larger `i32` without overflowing?

```
let a: i16 = i16::max_value();
let b: i16 = i16::max_value();
let c: i32 = a + b; // throws EO308 "Expected `u32`, found `u16`
```

Answer (score 11):

There are no integral promotions or implicit casts in Rust, so you must do all type conversions manually.

For casts, you can use `<value> as <type>`. However, if the destination type is a superset of the original one and converting it cannot lose information (such as your case), you can self-document that by using `<type>::from`:

```rust
let a: i16 = i16::max_value();
let b: i16 = i16::max_value();
let c: i32 = i32::from(a) + i32::from(b);
assert_eq!(c, 65534);
```

This particular case cannot overflow, but for other cases you can prevent overflows using `{integer}::checked_*()` functions:

```rust
let a: i16 = i16::max_value();
let b: i16 = i16::max_value();
let c: Option<i16> = a.checked_add(b);
assert_eq!(c, None); //overflow!
```

Note that overflowing an integer operation panics by default in debug builds.

If what you want is wrapping arithmetic, just like in old C, you can use `{integer}::wraping_*()`, with the additional bonus that it works for signed as well as unsigned values.

```rust
let a: i16 = i16::max_value();
let b: i16 = i16::max_value();
let c: i16 = a.wrapping_add(b);
assert_eq!(c, -2);
```

Comment: @PetrusTheron: Not really, it will generate exactly the same code. The idea is that Rust relies heavily in type inference, so if in the future your types change so that the casts may overflow, then this code will fail to compile.

Comment: Note that an overflow in typical integer addition only panics when compiled in debug mode.

Comment: "If what you want is wrapping arithmetic, just like in old C": [note that this is considered undefined behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/y4vIi1).

Comment: @E_net4: Not quite. Rust *the language* specifies that the result of an overflow is unspecified, and may be a panic. `rustc` *the compiler* allows to select one of two behaviors with a switch: panic or wrapping; furthermore, it also *defaults* to panicking in Debug and wrapping in Release, but the user can always change this. Ideally, `rustc` would want to *always* panic by default, however LLVM optimizes such code poorly, and the presence of panics hinders vectorization in general, so the default for Release had to be wrapping to match C performance *for now*.

Comment: @lights0123: This is true only for _signed overflow_. In C, unisgned overflow is well defined. I hinted at that in my answer, but I didn't want to get into those details, as this is not a question about C but Rust.

Comment: I'm surprised that rust defines `as` this way, since it seems to promote unexpected behaviour. Assuming it's needed by some, I would have expected `as` to refuse to compile if truncation or wrapping is required, and `from` to truncate/wrap

Answer (score 1):

You can cast them both to `i32` before addition.

```
let c: i32 = (a as i32) + (b as i32);
```

Comment: Using `From` or `TryFrom` would be more idiomatic nowadays.

Comment: @mcarton: good to know, thanks. I'm not even a rust newbie. Just an embryo of one :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `as` works fine, it's just not maintenance-friendly. If the type of `a` switches to `i64` the operation `a as i32` will continue to compile, now silently truncating the value. `From` is defined only for conversion which cannot fail, so would stop compiling. `TryFrom` is defined for all conversions, but returns an `Option<Target>` which must be unwrapped at run-time; it is idiomatically used for conversions that *may* fail.